# Can't connect to PostgreSQL server running in Vagrant from host

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

There are similar questions but nothing worked for me. I have already added this line to my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host all all all trust
```

And this one to my `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

My networking settings in the Vagrantfile are:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.0"
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000, auto_correct: true
```

When I try to connect from the host, I get:

```
$ psql -h 10.0.0.0 -U <username> -d <database>
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running on host "10.0.0.0" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The same command from the guest works with no problems. What am I missing??

[UPDATE]

I changed the private network ip to "192.168.1.77" (got it from a working example) and it worked. Still don't know why 10.0.0.0 wasn't good though, since it is in the [reserved private address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces), so I'll leave the question unanswered.

Comment: it tells you if the port is opened for 5432 but you did not forward in your vagrantfile

Answer (score 4):

You need to forward the postgres port, you're only forwarding `3000`, not `5432`.

Comment: So, from what I think I understand about networking, I can either use port forwarding or simply create a private network so I can access any port without having to specify each of them in my Vagrantfile. If I forwarded, say, port 5433 in the host to 5432 in the guest, I'd be able to connect to the PostgreSQL server with `psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U <username> -d <database>`. But since I have a private network and the static ip 10.0.0.0 is assigned to the guest, I shouldn't need to do any port forwarding. I should be able to connect to 10.0.0.0 (port 5432 by default) instead of localhost:5433.

Comment: Just did the experiment and confirmed: by using port forwarding instead of private network, I managed to connect. I still don't know why I can't connect through the private network though, so I'll leave the question unanswered.

Comment: Dmitri you need to set the ip of your host in the postgresql config file.. Otherwise the server will reject connections from external ips.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to forwarding port 5432 to another port on my host machine in my Vagrantfile, I added the following to my pg_hba.conf file in my vagrant machine, restarted postgresql, and it finally allowed me to connect from the host:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
```

I found the suggestion here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11339

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason you could not connect is that technically `10.0.0.0` is the network address of the range `10.0.0.0/8` (and `10.255.255.255` is the broadcast address and should also not work). The first address of each range is the network address and is not allowed to be a routable host (similarly `192.168.0.0` should fail in the same way since it's a 16-bit block).